# Theme Installation Is Asking For Directory(Base Directory) Permission Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, directory, nginx-location

I have php and laravel framework theme. When I try to install its asking for "Base Directory"Permission. I don't know which dirctory is actually asking for? .And I tried these kinds of commands from StackOverflow. My server os is Alpine linux,Nginx,Php7.?
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jf50l.jpg)

```
chmod 775 $(find /var/www/html -type f)
chmod 775 -R /var/www/html
chmod -R a+rX *
```

Comment: what's your web server configuration (apache/nginx)?

Comment: Nginx-Php7.3 please sir give me any trick am doing this the whole day but am still stuck at this??

Comment: surely. what's DCM installation? I don't know it. for nginx you should search me your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf contnet and find root directive.